# MySQL open source reporting services

Tags: mysql, report

I am currently working on a project where reporting services are required.  The database back end is built using MySQL and I would like to have something with similar functionality to say SSRS.

Does anyone have any experience with an open source solution for this?  Any they would particularly recommend?  It would have to be accessed via a browser.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you say "reporting service" I suppose you mean "report programming and generating system." Is that right?

- Jasper - http://community.jaspersoft.com/
- BIRT - http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/
- Crystal Reports, if you can deal with an non-open-source system.

These all work fine with MySQL.

Unfortunately all these reporting systems are engaged in some ridiculous spin where they're telling themselves they are "business intelligence solutions"  rather than report programming schemes.  So, you'll do some digging through the marketing BS to find out solutions to simple problems like "how do I list sales of microbrew beer by zip code" or whatever you want to report about.

Comment: +1 BIRT is probably closer in functionality to SSRS, while Jasper has more in common with Crystal - both of the latter are "banded" report designers, while SSRS and BIRT have similar report item objects, such as tables, lists, matrix/crosstabs, etc.

Comment: new one since the post, is called ReportServer https://reportserver.net Appears to copy a lot of SSRS features. Even the name is a knock off.

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL reporting you could try one of the following. Unfortunately none of them are open source.

- [Smart report maker](http://mysqlreports.com)
- [MySQL Pivot table generator](http://mysqlpivottable.net/) - recommended if you want to create analytical & summary reports
- [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/) - very powerful

Answer (score 0):

For the PHP MYSQL Reporting tool, try [the Smart Report Engine](https://mysqlreports.com/mysql-reporting-tools/smart-report-engine/) You can use it as a native PHP engine or a larval package. with very few lines of code like the following code example, you can create a professional auto dynamic report from your project.

```
$report = new ReportOptions(SRE_PUBLIC_REPORT);
$report->select_tables(array("items"))
       ->set_grouping(array("country"))
       ->select_all_fields();
$engine = new CustomEngine($report);
$report_path = $engine->create_report();
```

[More code examples of using Smart Report Engine](https://mysqlreports.com/examples/)